# Query MySql retorna dados incompletos no Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Tenho uma view no banco de dados onde se eu consulta-la pelo MySql Workbench a consulta retorna 320 linhas, mas quando faço a mesma consulta pelo Visual Studio só retorna 11 e não consigo encontrar nenhum erro. Coloco abaixo todos os códigos envolvidos.

Chamada da classe ClassReport:

```
    private void FrmReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ClassReport classReport = new ClassReport();
        Reports.balizamento balizamento = new Reports.balizamento();

        classReport.blz(225);
        balizamento.SetDataSource(classReport.dtRelatorio);
        balizamento.Refresh();
        crReport.ReportSource = balizamento;
        classReport.Dispose();

    }
```

Código da ClassReport:

```
    using System;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    namespace ClassLibrary
    {
        public class ClassReport : IDisposable
        {
            ClassConexaoMysql conexaoMysql = new ClassConexaoMysql();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            public MySqlDataReader dr;
            private string mensagem;
            public DataTable dtRelatorio = new DataTable();
            public DataTable blz(int competicao)
            {
                //Comando MySQL
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM v_balizamento WHERE competicao_id = @competicao";
    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@competicao", competicao);
    
                //Conexão com o Banco de Dados
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conexaoMysql.conectar();
                    // executar o comando
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtRelatorio.Load(dr);
                }
                catch (MySqlException)
                {
                    this.mensagem = "Erro ao Consultar Banco de Dados";
                }
                return dtRelatorio;
    
            }
            ~ClassReport()
            {
                this.Dispose();
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                conexaoMysql.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

String de Conexão com o banco:

```
     static public string strConn = $"Persist Security Info=False;server={server};User Id={user};database={database};password={pass};" +
        $"Connection Timeout=10;Connection Lifetime = 10; Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=2;Pooling=false;AllowUserVariables=true;";
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O método dtRelatorio.Load "infere" a estrutura da tabela a partir dos dados. Como a origem é uma view, o método infere de maneira errada as chaves primárias sobreescrevendo registros cuja chave esteja duplicada.

Ao invés de utilizar o método Load do DataTable, pode-se utilizar o método Fill do MySqlDataAdapter (que não cria chave primária para a tabela).